Book Appointment FSL
I currently have a custom code using the standard class AppointmentBookingSlot Class. When an API get call is made for a specific appointment, the class is called to return the slots "slots = FSL.AppointmentBookingService.getSlots(serviceId, policy.Id, oH.id, tz,false)".
Then the returned value is added into a wrapper "res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(wrapper));".
However, as the standard method is using a synchronous process, an APEX CPU TIME LIMIT is getting triggered. We have the option to change the same class to asynchronous by changing the Field "FSL__Use_Async_Logic__c" of the ServiceAppointment record to TRUE.
When the async job runs, a record of an object called "FSL operation" is created. It has a JSON file containing the slots.
I would highly appreciate it if you had any suggestion on how I could adapt the code which is called by the API Get to retrieve the slots and sends it via the response.
Thank you.
